Edit /etc/sudoers file to mount cifs without sudo
I have Python scripts on a Linux server that mount cifs. They get executed via crond. I want to execute them via a specific user, but it will only do it with sudo or the root user.
I tried to edit the /etc/sudoers file accordingly:
...
username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/mount, /usr/bin/umount
...

I am still getting following error message:
This program is not installed setuid root -  "user" CIFS mounts not supported.


"it will only do it with sudo" you will still need to prefix the command with sudo even if you have configured it for NOPASSWD
